# How to take heap dump in Sun JDK 1.5 (windows) programmatically

Tags: java, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trigger Heap Dump of a 1.5 JVM running on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136125/trigger-heap-dump-of-a-1-5-jvm-running-on-windows)

I have successfully taken heap dump in Sun JDK 1.6 (Windows) through HotSpotMXBean and by using jmap . Now , I have to do the same thing in JDK 1.5(windows).

Now the problem is that , in JDK 1.5 (windows) there is no jmap  , neither does it support HotSpotMXBean. So , can you guide me how I can take heap  dump of a whole JVM in 1.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but What is meaning of heap dump I want to learn that.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: It's a dump of Java's current heapspace, can be used for debugging, memory analysis, leaks, thread performance etc.

Comment: I would use Java 6 just to take the heap dump. Unless your Java 5.0 program dies before you can take the dump it should be similar to what you would have got from Java 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options to take heap dump in JDK 5. See

- [HPROF](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html)
- [jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html)
- [Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Try as much as you can.

Comment: but jmap , jhat are not present in Sun JDK 1.5 (Windows) .